# Navigation bar color not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have been banging my head for a while trying to figure out why the color of my navigation bar is just not showing up. Please take a look at the following CSS to tell me what i'm doing wrong.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {

    border: 2px solid #000000;
    font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display:inline;
    font-family: ubuntu;
    background-color: #e1e3e4;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
}


body {
    background-color: #e1e3e4;
}

    p{
        font-family: ubuntu;

    }
```

this is the html for the document:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
            <title>Palliative Care Toolkit</title>
        </head>

    <body id= "page">

        <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar">
        <ul>


            <li href="#" class="button grow">What is Palliative Care?</li>
            <li>Who Needs Palliative Care?</li>
        <li>Taking about Palliative Care?</li>
        <li>How to Interact with Providers?</li>
        <li>Additional Resources?</li>
        </ul>
            </div>
        <p style="display:inline; font-size:30px; margin-top: 20px; position:fixed; margin-left: 30px; "> Palliative Care ToolKit </p>

    </div>
```

thanks so much for your help!
Jose

Comment: got some html for me?

Comment: what color did you applied?

Answer (score 0):

Because your navbar has `position:fixed`, it is no longer positioned in relation to `#header`. This means that `#header` acts like it has no content; which means it collapses in height. Simply give `#header` a height, or change the positioning method.

Comment: Thank you so much Dre. It finally worked for me. I didn't realize the solution was this simple!